# How would you read from a text file in C if you know the character coding, then display it on the console?

Tags: c, unicode, character-encoding

Consider this example in Java:

```
public final class Meh
{
    private static final String HELLO = "Hello world";

    private static final Charset UTF32 = Charset.forName("UTF-32");

    public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException
    {
        final Path tmpfile = Files.createTempFile("test", "txt");

        try (
            final Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(tmpfile, UTF32);
        ) {
            writer.write(HELLO);
        }

        final String readBackFromFile;

        try (
            final Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(tmpfile, UTF32);
        ) {
            readBackFromFile = CharStreams.toString(reader);
        }

        Files.delete(tmpfile);

        System.out.println(HELLO.equals(readBackFromFile));
    }
}
```

This program prints `true`. Now, some notes:

- a `Charset` in Java is a class wrapping a character coding, both ways; you can get a `CharsetDecoder` to decode a stream of bytes to a stream of characters, or a `CharsetEncoder` to encode a stream of characters into a stream of bytes;
- this is why Java has `char` vs `byte`;
- for historical reasons however, a `char` is only a 16bit unsigned number: this is because when Java was born, Unicode did not define code points outside of what is now known as the BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane; that is, any code points defined in range U+0000-U+FFFF, inclusive).

With all this out of the way, the code above performs the following:

- given some "text", represented here as a `String`, it first applies a transformation of this text into a byte sequence before writing it to a file;
- then it reads back that file: it is only a sequence of bytes, but then it applies the reverse transformation to find back the "original text" stored in it;
- note that `CharStreams.toString()` is not in the standard JDK; this is a class from Guava.

Now, as to C... My question is as follows:

- discussing the matter on [the C chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54304/c), I have learned that the C11 standard [has, with <uchar.h>, what seems to be appropriate to store a Unicode code point, regardless of the encoding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte);
- however, there doesn't seem to be the equivalent of Java's `Charset`; another comment on the chat room is that with C you're SOL but that C++ has codecvt...

And yes, I'm aware that UTF-32 is endianness-dependent; with Java, that is BE by default.

But basically: how would I program the above in C? Let's say I want to program the writing side or reading side in C, how would I do it?

Comment: I assume you don't want the answer to be about `[java]`?

Comment: I don't think "*this is why Java has char vs byte*" is entirely true .. You can good official link suggesting the same ??

Comment: @PeterLawrey it is just that I believe seasoned Java experts may have encountered the same issue and already investigated the matter more than I did

Comment: @hagrawal you can read the JLS about this, but that's pretty much how it is ;)

Comment: @fge such a seasoned java developer would still need to know enough about C. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey OK, agreed; still, does it warrant the removal of the tag? :/

Comment: @fge IMHO The tags should reflect the desired answer rather than technologies mentioned in the question.  You can always search by words in the question if that is what you want.

Comment: There are libraries that can perform character set conversions, such as GNU libiconv.

Answer (score 0):

In C, you'd typically use a library like *libiconv*, *libunistring*, or *ICU*.

If you only want to process UTF-32, you can directly write and read an array of 32-bit integers containing the Unicode code points, either in little or big endian. Unlike UTF-8 or UTF-16, a UTF-32 string doesn't need any special encoding and decoding. You can use any 32-bit integer type. I'd prefer C99's `uint32_t` over C11's `char32_t`. For example:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    // Could also contain non-ASCII code points.
    static const uint32_t hello[] = {
        'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ',
        'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'
    };
    static size_t num_chars = sizeof(hello) / sizeof(uint32_t);

    const char *path = "test.txt";

    FILE *outstream = fopen(path, "wb");

    // Write big endian 32-bit integers        
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_chars; i++) {
        uint32_t code_point = hello[i];

        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            int c = (code_point >> ((3 - j) * 8)) & 0xFF;
            fputc(c, outstream);
        }
    }

    fclose(outstream);

    FILE *instream = fopen(path, "rb");

    // Get file size.
    fseek(instream, 0, SEEK_END);
    long file_size = ftell(instream);
    rewind(instream);

    if (file_size % 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "File contains partial UTF-32");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (file_size > SIZE_MAX) {
        fprintf(stderr, "File too large");
        exit(1);
    }

    size_t num_chars_in = file_size / sizeof(uint32_t);
    uint32_t *read_back = malloc(file_size);

    // Read big endian 32-bit integers        
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_chars_in; i++) {
        uint32_t code_point = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            int c = fgetc(instream);
            code_point |= c << ((3 - j) * 8);
        }

        read_back[i] = code_point;
    }

    fclose(instream);

    bool equal = num_chars == num_chars_in
                 && memcmp(hello, read_back, file_size) == 0;
    printf("%s\n", equal ? "true" : "false");

    free(read_back);

    return 0;
}
```

(Most error checks omitted for brevity.)

Compiling and running this program:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 -Wall so.c -o so
$ ./so
true
$ hexdump -C test.txt
00000000  00 00 00 48 00 00 00 65  00 00 00 6c 00 00 00 6c  |...H...e...l...l|
00000010  00 00 00 6f 00 00 00 20  00 00 00 77 00 00 00 6f  |...o... ...w...o|
00000020  00 00 00 72 00 00 00 6c  00 00 00 64              |...r...l...d|
0000002c
```